# How to create a new entry in a table whilst maintaining the correct foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple 1 to many table relationship between the table challenge and entry. 
I would like a user (itself a one to many with challenge) to be able to create an entry and for this to also update the challenge. I don't know how to do this. The approach I have taken is as follows:

A div is created on the page from an ajax call that lists all the challenges. The user then clicks a challenge and then can press a button to create a new entry in a new entry form (also an ajax call). Basically I want the user to be able to create a new entry and for it to have the correct challenge_id associated with it

```
schema.rb

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150719082241) do

  create_table "challenges", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "pointsSpend"
    t.string   "rules"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "entries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "blob"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "challenge_id"
    t.string   "picture"
  end


  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end
end



challenge.rb

class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :entries
    belongs_to :user
end

entry.rb

class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :challenge
end
```

in the entry_controller.rb

```
def create
  @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
  @entry = Entry.new(entry_params)
  @entry.challenge_id = @challenge.id
  respond_to do |format|
    if @entry.save
      format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }
      render :layout => false
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      render :layout => false
    end
  end
end
```

in the entry.rb model

```
def entry_params
  params.require(:entry).permit(:id, :blobby, :challenge_id)
end
```

However this doesn't update the entry table with the challenge_id. What am I doing wrong? Is it because the challenge_id parameter is not being passed to the entry form or something?

in the challenges_controller.rb

```
def create
    @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params.merge({user_id: current_user.id}))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @challenge.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'Challenge was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @challenge }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @challenge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The form page for the user to create a new challenge

```
<%= form_for(@challenge) do |f| %>

  <% if @challenge.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@challenge.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this challenge from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @challenge.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


    <%= f.label :pointsSpend %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :pointsSpend%>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rules %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :rules %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and the form to create a new entry

```
<%= form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
  <% if @entry.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@entry.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this entry from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @entry.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :blob %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :blob %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The ajax calls to render all these forms

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require messages
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .


$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#ChallengeButton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "/challenges/new",
          success: function(response){
              $('#challengeCentre').html(response);
          }
        })
      });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#ChallengeListButton').click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "challenges",
          success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
              $('#challengeListCentre').html(response);
          }
        })
      });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#ChallengeJoinButton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "/entries/new",
          success: function(response){
              $('#challengeJoinCentre').html(response);
          }
        })
      });
      });
```

Comment: seems like your @challenge is blank. which means that params[:challenge_id] is nil or there is no challenge for that challenge id. Can you please show the parameters being passed to create action to entries_controller. and the page from where you are creating entry

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: im going to post this as answer. unable to use @ sign here.

Answer (score 0):

so you see there isn't any field for challenge_id in entry form.
if your routes are nested. replace this

```
 <%= form_for(@entry) do |f| %>
```

with this

```
 <%= form_for([@challenge, @entry]) do |f| %>.
```

and it will pass @challenge as well. see this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Though nested routes are the best option but if your routes are not nested. you can add hidden field in your event form like this .

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag :challenge_id,  @challenge.id %>
```

and you can access in event create action like this

```
@challenge = Challenge.find(params[:challenge_id])
```

or you can do this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :challenge_id, value:  @challenge.id %>
```

and it will automatically make the challenge_id within event params and set challenge_id for event.